# SYN ACK after ACK with a CORBA server

Tags: linux, tcp, corba

We have experienced an issue with a CORBA server. A client host connected to this server was sending some CORBA commands that did not get any response from the server. when we took a `tcpdump` (it is a Linux machine), we saw the following:

- client sent SYN
- server replied with SYN,ACK
- client then sent ACK
- server sent again and again (3 times) the SYN,ACK and eventually after three * attempts it sent RST.

Does anyone know why this happened? Why would syn, ack be sent after client ACK?

Comment: This happens because the SYN-ACK is lost, which is most likely because of a misconfigured firewall or NAT somewhere.

Comment: If the server's re-sending the SYN,ACK, it's probably not receiving the ACK. Check your firewall rules (both on the server, and on any devices between the client and server).